# How do I exclude only .min.js files in gulp task, while staying in same directory?

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, wildcard

I am trying to set up a build system for my front end work though I am running into a problem where it loops processing files over and over again. This is a problem with my js processing since I am not sure how to exclude just the files with .min as a suffix.

The task goes as follows

```
return gulp.src(["!dev/js/*.min.js", "dev/js/*.js"])
        .pipe(plumber())
        .pipe(browserify())
        .pipe(smaps.init())
            .pipe(uglyify({preserveComments: "license"}))
        .pipe(smaps.write())
        .pipe(rename({suffix: ".min"}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(output_dir));
```

Though what I have found is that it still targets the .min.js files since they are also seen as .js files. I have messed around with a few different configurations of these wildcards but I keep ending up with the task looping creating `example.min.js` then `example.min.min.js` then `example.min.min.min.js` etc.

So, how can I just process files that do not include the .min prefix?

Comment: Try putting `./` at the beginning just to see

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use [negated patterns](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/API.md#gulpsrcglobs-options) to exclude .min.js files.

```
gulp.src(['dev/js/*.js', '!dev/js/*.min.js'])
```

Comment: Yes this is what I have been using, but it produces the repetitive starting and finishing. Here is a screenshot: https://i.imgur.com/XR5oh1R.png

Comment: Woops!, It turns out that I had not included ignoring the file in my watch statement... :/ All working now, thanks for this answer anyway, made me look through the other statements that called the task. So, every time the js file was changed, the js min file was changed which also called the watch function which executed the task. Not really sure why it was looping over and over after those two calls, but it's all fixed now.

Answer (score 4):

if you want to do it in only one string you can use:

```
gulp.src(["dev/js/!(*.min)*.js"])
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `gulp` command.

```
const
    gulpIgnore = require( 'gulp-ignore' ),
    uglify = require( 'gulp-uglify' ),
    jshint = require( 'gulp-jshint' ),
    condition = './**/*.min.js';

gulp.task( 'task', function() {
    gulp.src( './**/*.js' )
        .pipe( jshint() )
        .pipe( gulpIgnore.exclude( condition ) )
        .pipe( uglify() )
        .pipe( gulp.dest( './dist/' ) );
} );
```

In the `condition` you specify your directory. `../` to go backward, `/dir` to go forwards

Comment: I had tried this, but it hadn't seem to work. I will retry with your example. *EDIT* Alright, tested it out and turns out it was something else, see comment on Himani's Answer.